# How do I use scipy.interpolate.splrep to interpolate a curve?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

Using some experimental data, I cannot for the life of me work out how to use splrep to create a B-spline. The data are here: http://ubuntuone.com/4ZFyFCEgyGsAjWNkxMBKWD

Here is an excerpt:

```
#Depth  Temperature
1   14.7036
-0.02   14.6842
-1.01   14.7317
-2.01   14.3844
-3  14.847
-4.05   14.9585
-5.03   15.9707
-5.99   16.0166
-7.05   16.0147
```

and here's a plot of it with depth on y and temperature on x:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev

tdata = np.genfromtxt('t-data.txt', 
                      skip_header=1, delimiter='\t')
depth = tdata[:, 0]
temp = tdata[:, 1]

# Find the B-spline representation of 1-D curve:
tck = splrep(depth, temp)
### fails here with "Error on input data" returned. ###
```

I know I am doing something bleedingly stupid, but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to have your values from smallest to largest :).  It shouldn't be a problem for you @a different ben, but beware readers from the future, `depth[indices]` will throw a `TypeError` if depth is a list instead of a numpy array!

```
>>> indices = np.argsort(depth)
>>> depth = depth[indices]
>>> temp = temp[indices]
>>> splrep(depth, temp)
(array([-7.05, -7.05, -7.05, -7.05, -5.03, -4.05, -3.  , -2.01, -1.01,
        1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ]), array([ 16.0147    ,  15.54473241,  16.90606794,  14.55343229,
        15.12525673,  14.0717599 ,  15.19657895,  14.40437622,
        14.7036    ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ]), 3)
```

Hat tip to @FerdinandBeyer for the suggestion of `argsort` instead of my ugly "zip the values, sort the zip, re-assign the values" method.

Comment: You should probably use the `np.argsort()` function to sort the data: `indices = np.argsort(depth); depth = depth[indices]; temp = temp[indices]`.  This saves you the list-of-tuples detour.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer That's a much better solution than mine! Editing it in now.

Comment: I got an error when I tried to do `depth[indices]` but please let me know if there is a nicer way than `[depth[i] for i in indices]`.  Either way it's a much cleaner solution, thanks.

Comment: `depth[indices]` is equivalent to `np.array([depth[i] for i in indices])`, but much faster!  If you get an error (what error?!), make sure that `depth` is a NumPy array, not a list!  I used this approach on the OP's posted data and it works fine.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer Ahh I see, I get a TypeError because I'm using a list.  Thanks for the help, I certainly learned something about numpy today :D

Comment: thanks! One more: @NolenRoyalty @FerdinandBeyer  So because the depth is already in reverse order I could also set `depth = depth*-1`? In my case it wouldn't matter until plotting. Depth is only negative below ground by convention.

Comment: @adifferentben I'd assume that that would produce the same results, and you could label your graph to make it clear.  That's a strange method for solving your problem though(in my opinion).

Comment: @adifferentben: If you know that `depth` is always sorted in descending order, just reverse the arrays when passing them to `splrep`: `x, y = tdata.T; tck = splrep(x[::-1], y[::-1])`.  This way you get the spline in the original data domain.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer This is new notation to me, but thanks, I'll look at it. NolenRoyalty I prefer the word 'different' as you might have noticed.

Comment: @adifferentben: It is the advanced slicing syntax: `array[start:stop:step]`.  `a[::-1]` means: whole array (implicit start and stop) with step -1, i.e., reversed.  `x, y = tdata.T` is a convenient way to create views for the two columns.